# Manga or manhwa where the main character pretends to follow the demon lord after failing to escape

Tags: story-identification, manga

the mc was trying to escape the demon lords castle. but somehow fails miserably at each attempt so he decides to pretend to follow the demon lord and find another way of escaping like maybe during a mission. He pretends to take a hit and die from the hero.so that he can escape but only to find out that everyone around him is surprisingly too weak.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And was the demon lord male or female?